Socket can't find AF_UNIX attribute
I'm using an Arch Linux machine and trying to run the following code from a Python file.
import socket
import sys

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(sys.platform)
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

and it keeps telling me that
AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_UNIX'

Things tried

Some posts claim this error occurs on Windows but obviously that isn't the case.

sys.platform prints linux


Code works on my Mac which was running Python3.9

Downgraded from Python3.12 to Python3.9 on the Linux machine and still no luck


socket.AF_INET has the same issue
running python -c "import socket; socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM) returns the same error
error when using system binary python, conda python and venv python
running it in the interactive shell has no issue however.


Can you post a [mre], i.e. the whole code with import statements and everything.

The error is caused by an unlucky choice of variable name. The variable socket shadows the module of the same name.
The first time the line is run, it works fine:
import socket

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# works fine, but now socket points to the object returned by the socket.socket() call
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# error!

Solution: use a different variable name, e.g. sock:
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


found my error which was that i had named my python file socket.py. thank you very much for the suggestion.

@Praanto glad you solved your problem. Feel free to self-answer if my answer doesn't really work out. However, the next issue you'd have run into is the variable name.
